# PHPUnit - Odd behaviour (group runs)

Tags: php, phpunit

I have some odd behavior with PHPUnit tests. What's happening is when I run them as a group, the last 5 fail. When I re-run the failed tests, they pass.

[image: Failed and passing tests]

[image: Passing after re-run]

When I run those failed tests by themselves, they pass as well. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? I tried from running them in isolate processes, disabling caching (HTTP, memcache), logging the results, but the problem persists from time to time. (It behaves randomly, yet to try the restart)

Comment: Is it possible that some of your tests have side effects which are affecting subsequent tests.  Try moving the first failed method up to see if it still fails and if this affects anything else.

Comment: Move ot up? I have tests in separate files, with one test function per file on the screenshot. Will it make a difference?

Comment: As I have no idea what the test do and the only thing you say is that if they are executed differently they work it is all I can suggest.  Sometimes tests may change data and unless this data is set inside each module then it's possible that it is left in a state which isn't what your expecting.

Comment: They run through an algorithm on the server which does not modify any data, it only reads from the database to form the response. I'm sending a request via $this->json to the REST API in the test, parse the response and assert the results

Comment: Have tried to separate it into different folders in “test” directory and using custom phpunit.xml configuration file with all caching disabled - seems to aid, but not always. Now got to try running all folders in the root directory to see if it repeats itself.